# "in response to" vs "for response to"?

Tags: differences, idioms, prepositions, expressions, expression-choice

"I am writing in response to your mail."

What does it mean by "in" in this sentence?

Is "I am writing for response to your mail." acceptable?

Comment: One acronym: ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, *response* is referring to "a verbal or written answer" or, simply, "a reaction":

> [**response**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/response?q=in+response)
>
> - a verbal or written answer: *we received 400 applications in response to one job ad.*
> - a reaction to something: *an honors degree course in Japanese has been established in response to an increasing demand.*

The preposition *[in](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in?showCookiePolicy=true)* is therefore more suitable:

> [**in**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in?showCookiePolicy=true)
>
> 3. indicating a state, situation, or condition ⇒ in a deep sleep, standing in silence

If you are a native speaker of English or you've familiarized yourself with linguistic expressions in English (by reading many English books and listening to many English podcasts, etc), you can tell straight away that the expression *writing for response* simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, only *in response* is possible. Prepositions like *in* have many uses, and, if you are a foreign learner of English, the simplest course is to learn them as parts of complete phrases.

Comment: Barrie England, would you care to explain the difference between 'in response to' and 'as a response to' in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The correct phrase is the latter: *in response to*. Another very appropriate phrase would be *in a response to*. If you do not want to use the word “*in*”, consider using *as a response to*.

Comment: _As a response to_ would be used in a different context.